# Open source framework for Cloud Video Recording

Tags: video, cloud, capture, recording

I am trying to build an application. One of the requirements for the application is to enable streaming video capture in a public cloud. I was wondering if there is an open source framework already out there that I can look at.

Comment: Question seems to be bit vague ..do you want process the video data in cloud .. Actually capture video in cloud doesnt make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a server that can accept a video stream as an input and either save it as a file or transcode it and stream it some place else, then VideoLan may be what you are looking for.

Their streaming page is here:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo_New/#Unix_systems

If you want an example specifically of saving a streamed video to a file take a look at the first example at this link:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/